# CKEditor Firefox unable to select text in the textbox

Tags: firefox, ckeditor5

We have firefox and ckeditor 5. Below is the version and the code being used. We can click and type but if we try to select anything with our mouse or touch, we cannot. We can navigate with the cursor arrows but that is it.

Using keditor5.37.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js

```
<textarea name="txtDescriptionLong" rows="6" cols="20" id="txtDescriptionLong" style="width:100%;">
</textarea>
<script>
const editorConfigurationtxtDescriptionLong = {
toolbar: {
plugins: [ 'Autoformat', 'Autoexpand' ],
autoExpand: true,
items: [
paragraph',
'|',
'bold',
'italic',
'|',
'link',
'bulletedList',
'numberedList',
'|',
'undo',
'redo'
]
}
};

ClassicEditor
.create(document.querySelector('textarea[name="txtDescriptionLong"]'), editorConfigurationtxtDescriptionLong)
.catch(error => {
console.error(error);
}
);
</script>
```

Tried Edge/Chrome and work perfectly.
Latest version of Firefox, no plugins/extensions/etc. are installed.

I expect that when I type in a box I should be able to go back, select text, and copy the said text.